# Ограничение на размер динамического массива в Си++

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, language-lawyer

Этот код компилируется и [работает нормально](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1109985/178988):

```
long long n = 6'000'000'000;
auto *a = new char[n];
```

А если написать просто:

```
auto *a = new char[6'000'000'000];
```

то происходит ошибка компиляции:

> error C2148: общий размер массива не должен превышать 0x7fffffff байт

Компилирую в VS2017 под x64.

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017
>   Версия 15.9.6
>   VisualStudio.15.Release/15.9.6+28307.344
>   Microsoft .NET Framework
>   Версия 4.8.03752
>
> Установленная версия: Community
>
> Visual C++ 2017   00369-60000-00001-AA117
>   Microsoft Visual C++ 2017

Чем обусловлено такое поведение? Соответствует ли оно стандарту? Есть ли вообще ограничение на максимальный размер массива, который можно выделить?

Comment: [Видимо все-таки не под x64.](https://godbolt.org/z/p3pjr9) А максимальный размер массива обычно ограничен гранулированностью памяти.

Comment: @user7860670, под x64: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b12Rv.png

Comment: Как-то даже неудобно человека с почти 100к репутации тыкать в очевидные вещи, но x64 - это просто название варианта сборки, а платформа могла быть случайно изменена в настройках проекта, или что-то подобное. Вставьте в код какую-нибудь простую проверку, чтобы быть уверенным `static_assert(8 == sizeof(void *), "not x64");`

Comment: @user7860670 1. это свежесозданный чистый проект. 2. Если бы там x32, то каким образом программа со значением в переменной работает корректно? 3. Сейчас проверю.

Comment: @user7860670, https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ipb1P.png

Comment: А что за версия студии и конкретно компилятора? x32 Программа со значением в переменной будет (неявно) преобразовывать long long в 32 битный size_t аргумент оператора new. @HolyBlackCat А я же уже привел ссылку на godbolt со студией и там не воспроизводится на x64.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ну там wine. А у меня живая студия. `Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 
Версия 15.9.6
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.9.6+28307.344
Microsoft .NET Framework
Версия 4.8.03752

Установленная версия: Community`

Comment: @user7860670, `Visual C++ 2017   00369-60000-00001-AA117
Microsoft Visual C++ 2017`

Comment: хм, может действительно это была бага в старой версии. Студия 2017 уже доросла до версии 15.9.21 В 2019 тоже не воспроизводится. В общем, обновляйтесь.

Comment: В VС++ 2017 19.16.27038 (15.9.21), x64 - компилируется без проблем.

Comment: `g++ (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2) 9.2.1 20191008` тоже компилит

Comment: [Array size error x64 process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803162/array-size-error-x64-process)

Comment: @wololo, хм.. С 2010го пролежал баг, а недавно починили?

Comment: Не знаю :) Попробуйте добавить константу: `const long long n = 6'000'000'000;` Если не компилируется, то похоже, что так.

Comment: @wololo, попробовал - не компилируется.

Comment: Касательно последнего вопроса в вашем вопросе. Ограничения на максимальный размер массива есть. 1) Невозможно сконструировать массив размером больше чем `SIZE_MAX` [пруф](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#2). 2) Реализации могут ограничивать максимальный размер объекта, который можно выделить с помощью `new`, на своё усмотрение [пруф](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#9.3).

Comment: @wololo, ну про size_t логично. Ответ-то будешь писать?

Comment: Всё что мог сказать по вашему вопросу, я уже написал в комментариях.

Comment: @wololo, ну так напиши это в ответ.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, так он же ссылку на вопрос на enSO дал - это баг VS. Кстати, а почему `SIZE_MAX` 2\*\*63-1, а не 2\*\*64-1?

Comment: @Qwertiy Ошибся, `2^64-1` конечно. Лучше удалю коммент, похоже я читать не умею. :/